# How to "hack" GNU screen to be able of being executed without a tty?

Tags: php, gnu-screen

I need to be able of running `GNU screen` using `php` since my panel works with `PHP`. If there's isn't a way, is there an alternative that allows me to send commands to screen?

Like at screen: `screen -S 9274 -p 0 -X stuff '(command here)'\015`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nohup` command which is designed for such operations:

> `nohup` - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

You can also start `screen` in *detached mode* with the `-d -m` parameters:

> `-d -m`   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.